# Как исправить свою некорректную работу на git?

Tags: git

Чего то натворил на гите теперь очень многие файлы появились

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

=======
>>>>>>> e10f49a05efad469c142c965d89fb5196bab3dbb
```

ну а дальше старый и новый код. Точно понимаю, что на репозитории такого нет.
Как мне такое исправить то есть заново закачать все файлы с репозитория?

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса. "заново закачать все файлы с репозитория" - так ведь можно просто удалить проект и повторно клонировать. Либо откатить все изменения.

Comment: @AlexandrSysoev а как откатить изменения

Comment: Это конфликты при слиянии. Вы можете вручную удалить ненужные строки, и добавить файлы для коммита. Либо Вы можете использовать сторонние утилиты для разрешения конфликтов в git (погуглите)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего Вы делали git pull и произошел автоматический merge. Ничего страшно, обычное дело. Если это все не нужно, то скорее всего поможет команда `git merge --abort` (Но смержить нужно будет заново). Более правильный способ - смержить.

Открываете в любимом ide свой проект и ищите вхождения строки `"======="`, смотрите и оставляете правильный кусок кода. Потом для всех файлов `git add` и коммитите как обычно.

Также, возможно, Вы делали rebase (с кем не бывает) - тогда отмена - `git rebase --abort`.